# Qt parent of layout?

Tags: c++, qt

If I have the following code:

```
QWidget* plannerLeftDisplay = new QWidget(this);
QVBoxLayout* plannerLeftLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
plannerLeftLayout->addWidget(new UASListWidget());
plannerLeftDisplay->setLayout(plannerLeftLayout);
```

Then who is going to be the parent of the `plannerLeftLayout`?
I understand in this case the `UASListWidget` will have `plannerLeftDisplay` as parent, but what about `plannerLeftLayout`?

Comment: it will be `null`, isn't it?

Comment: won't setlayout give it a parent?

Comment: It's seems [you're right](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout)

Comment: I am just confused by qt's doc: If layout is the layout manger on a different widget, setLayout() will reparent the layout and make it the layout manager for this widget.  The QWidget will take ownership of layout. So if the layout originally has NULL parent, will QWidget take ownership of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plannerLeftDisplay` is a parent, run next code:

```
this->setObjectName("this");
QWidget* plannerLeftDisplay = new QWidget(this);
plannerLeftDisplay->setObjectName("plannerLeftDisplay");
QVBoxLayout* plannerLeftLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
plannerLeftLayout->addWidget(new QWidget());
plannerLeftDisplay->setLayout(plannerLeftLayout);
qDebug() << "parent is "<< plannerLeftLayout->parent();
```

Output will be:

> parent is  QWidget(0x2844a2c0, name = "plannerLeftDisplay")

See [Qt source code](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp#L9143):

```
void QWidget::setLayout(QLayout *l)
{
    if (!l) {
        qWarning("QWidget::setLayout: Cannot set layout to 0");
        return;
    }
    if (layout()) {
        if (layout() != l)
            qWarning("QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout \"%s\" on %s \"%s\", which already has a"
                     " layout", l->objectName().toLocal8Bit().data(), metaObject()->className(),
                     objectName().toLocal8Bit().data());
        return;
    }

    QObject *oldParent = l->parent();
    //in your case it is NULL
    if (oldParent && oldParent != this) {
        if (oldParent->isWidgetType()) {
            // Steal the layout off a widget parent. Takes effect when
            // morphing laid-out container widgets in Designer.
            QWidget *oldParentWidget = static_cast<QWidget *>(oldParent);
            oldParentWidget->takeLayout();
        } else {
            qWarning("QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout \"%s\" on %s \"%s\", when the QLayout already has a parent",
                     l->objectName().toLocal8Bit().data(), metaObject()->className(),
                     objectName().toLocal8Bit().data());
            return;
        }
    }

    Q_D(QWidget);
    l->d_func()->topLevel = true;
    d->layout = l;
    //reparent procedure
    if (oldParent != this) { //NULL really != this
        l->setParent(this);  //so layout has a parent now
        l->d_func()->reparentChildWidgets(this);
        l->invalidate();
    }

    if (isWindow() && d->maybeTopData())
        d->topData()->sizeAdjusted = false;
}
```

It should be so, because when some widget has layout and should be deleted, you don't need delete layout manually, all will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

"if the layout originally has NULL parent, will QWidget take ownership of it?" Yes. Incidentally, you don't need to use explicit heap allocations, and you can set the layout on a widget by passing the widget to the layout's constructor. For example:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  ...
  QWidget mainWidget;
  ...
  QWidget plannerLeftDisplay(mainWidget);
  QVBoxLayout plannerLeftLayout(&plannerLeftDisplay);
  UASListWidget listWidget;
  plannerLeftLayout.addWidget(&listWidget);
  ...
  mainWidget.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

or

```
class X : public QWidget {
  QWidget plannerLeftDisplay;
  QVBoxLayout plannerLeftLayout;
  UASListWidget listWidget;
  ...
  X(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent), 
    plannerLeftLayout(&plannerLeftDisplay)
  {
    plannerLeftLayout.addWidget(&listWidget);
    ...
  }
};
```